# How do I reset the recently used commands in Arduino IDE 2?

Tags: arduino-ide-2

I am recording videos on Arduino IDE version 2. In one of the videos I want to explain how to enable a specific setting via the advanced properties. This requires using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (command palette).

However, my Arduino IDE now shows some commands I have used recently (sorry, screenshot is in German).

[image: Arduino IDE 2 Command palette]

That's not the default. If someone has just installed Arduino IDE, he would need to scroll until he finds the entry. How do I reset the recently used items, so that I can record a proper video which requires scrolling?

Resetting the workbench layout does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. open the command palette
2. search and choose Preferences: Open Settings (UI)
3. in the preferences window, search for the setting `workbench.commandPalette.history`
4. set that value to 0 and it will not save the recent commands